# CSS list combining counters increase level and counter with letters in a deeper level

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to styles an ordered list where i want all the outer list elements to have numeric list style and inner list item to have letters.

The below is my structure.

```
 <div class="subitems">
    <ol><li>This is a list with numeric list style
        <ol><li>This is a list with numeric list style
            <ol class="rulebook-alpha"><li>This is a list with numeric list style</li>
                <li>This is a list with numeric list style</li>
            </ol></li>
            <li>This is a list with numeric list style</li>
        </ol></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

This is my css

```
div.subitems {
    ol {
        list-style-type: none;
        counter-reset: item;
        padding-left: 20px;
        li {
            counter-increment: item;
            padding: 0 0 20px 5px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 0;

            &::before {
                content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
                display: table-cell;
                position: absolute;
                left: -22px;
            }
            ol.rulebook-alpha {
                counter-reset: alpha;
                padding-left: 30px;

                li {
                    padding: 20px 0 0 10px;

                    &::before {
                        counter-increment: alpha;
                        content: "("counter(alpha, lower-alpha) ") ";
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
 
}
```

This is my output
[image]

My aim is to have 1.2 instead of 1.4 could you anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made it more complicated that it needed to be :)

I also suggest you to remove the absolute positioning, negative margins, table-cell display and z-index, which are not necessary.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
   counter-increment: item;
   content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
.rulebook-alpha {
  counter-reset: alpha;
}
.rulebook-alpha li:before {
  counter-increment: alpha;
  content: "(" counter(alpha, lower-alpha) ") ";
}
```

```html
<div class="subitems">
   <ol>
      <li>
         This is a list with numeric list style
         <ol>
            <li>
               This is a list with numeric list style
               <ol class="rulebook-alpha">
                  <li>This is a list with alphabetic list style</li>
                  <li>This is a list with alphabetic list style</li>
               </ol>
            </li>
            <li>This is a list with numeric list style</li>
         </ol>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```