# CSS Counters with different counter display in every level without extra classes

Tags: html, css, sass, html-lists

I am trying to do an ordered list (Terms and condition content) with a numeric value at the root, lower alpha for the second, and roman on the third. I found a SO guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711921/css-list-combining-counters-increase-level-and-counter-with-letters-in-a-deeper), but it requires adding a class on the second layer. Unfortunately the content will be added via a WYSIWYG editor by staff so adding extra classes manually is not possible(?).

The code below output a standard counter. The outcome will be `2.1` being replaced with `a` and `2.1.1` will be replaced with `i`.

[Sample list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep83R.png). *Can't embed the whole image :(

Any advice is appreciated.

```
.numbered_list{
counter-reset: list-number;
ol {
    padding-left: 40px;
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-reset:count;
    li{
        color: red;
        counter-increment:count;

        &::marker{
            content: counters(count, '.', decimal) ') ';
        }

        &:before{
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the anser on the question you linked, you simply need to change the CSS selectors.

For each additional level you want to target, add another `ol` to the selector list.
In a production environment, you would probably prepend all of the selectors with your *wysiwyg* editor class.

```css
/* first level */

ol {
  counter-reset: l1;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li:before {
  counter-increment: l1;
  content: counter(l1) " ";
}


/* second level */

ol ol {
  counter-reset: l2;
}

ol ol li:before {
  counter-increment: l2;
  content: counter(l1) "." counter(l2) " ";
}


/* third level */

ol ol ol {
  counter-reset: l3;
}

ol ol ol li:before {
  counter-increment: l3;
  content: counter(l1) "." counter(l2) "." counter(l3) " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    First Level

    <ol>
      <li>
        Second Level
        <ol>
          <li>Third Level</li>
          <li>Third Level</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Second Level</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<p>a paragraph, followed by another list</p>

<ol>
  <li>
    First Level

    <ol>
      <li>
        Second Level
        <ol>
          <li>Third Level</li>
          <li>Third Level</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Second Level</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  Just need to comment properly so it's easier to identify which level is which. 

Now  all I need to check is how not to terminate the list and start a new one if a paragraph is added. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer and added a paragraph and a second list. The list will automatically restart. That is what `ol { counter-reset: l1; }` does: every time a new first level  `ol` is created, it starts the counter from the beginning.